# Keynavigation using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyboard

I want to use keynavigation and found this library that looks very nice: [Click here](http://nekman.github.io/keynavigator/#link). I've started to try it out and created the following HTML-code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Key navigation</title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://nekman.github.io/keynavigator/keynavigator.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="navigateTest">
        <li>Test 1</li>
        <li>Test 2</li>
        <li>Test 3</li>

    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

And of course the following Javascript code (index.js):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('ul#navigateTest li').keynavigator(/* optional settings */);
});
```

But when i run the project the key navigation dosent work. What I am defining by dosent work is that I was excpecting the library would add some styling to the element to display the selected element. Do I need some sort of css styling applied to the code?

Comment: Please define "dosent work". What your code does, and what you expect it to do instead?

Comment: Why are you adding jQuery twice?

Comment: Include the `/* optional settings */` maybe the error is there `:)`.

Comment: added jquery twice by a mistake, sorry. Updated question now

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is of course to add some css styling to the currently selected HTML-element, by telling the javascript what css class name you should add to the HTML-element.

Create a css document and include a class into it like this:

```
.test{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Then reference to the css in the HTML of course like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="super.css">
```

And in the end, tell the javascript what class to add to the html-element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul#navigateTest li').keynavigator({activeClass: "test"});
});
```